# How to add a link to view history

Tags: netsuite

How do I add to the tables that I create this link "history" to display the history. According to this picture.

https://i.gyazo.com/a1671799cccfe5334ba918ec4c0fdb90.png

I wish I could add this same link to my tables.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, just the style is different. I tried to change the style, but this didn't work.
Hope its help you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJjgh.png)

Note: Its only use in view recordMode,not applicable edit/create mode
There are two points:
1: Add lineField type is **inline HTML**;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3eUs.png)
2: Using userevent script (beforeLoad Fun) to set the href,like this

```js
for (var i = 0; i < linenum; i++) {
    var url = "you want link";
    var url_href = "<a href='javascript:void nlOpenWindow(%22" + url + "%22, %22historypopup%22, %22width=750,height=1000,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes%22)'>history</a>";
    recObj.setLineItemValue('item', 'fieldId', i + 1, url_href);
}
```